# How do I get the background image in header to remain fixed, and header to be smaller than full screen?

Tags: html, css, header, background-image

I'm so new to this, so I really do apologise for my ignorance!

The header on my page is wider than a full screen browser. How do I get the header narrower, so it fits within the screen (ideally, with a small white border left around it)?

When I resize my browser, the background image changes, making the header text unreadable as it moves over the sky in the image. How do I get the picture to 'stay still'/ in position?

The code I'm using is below. Hope I've made some sense... (coding is the most fun I've had for ages, so glad there's a community to help me past my blocks, so thank you in advance!)

```
<head>
<link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>You're beautiful.</title>
<style>
    header {
        text-align: left;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/adSgDvK.jpg");
        width:100%;       
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-position:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        padding: 30px;
        font-family: courier;
        border: 7px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-position: fixed;
    }
    img {
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
        border: 7px solid white;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
        padding-bottom: 70px;
        vertical-align: super;
        line-height: 70%;
        height: 300px;
        color: white;
    }
     ul {
        padding: 10px;
        background: black;
        margin-bottom: -30px;
        margin-left: -30px;
    }
     li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a
        {
        color: white;
    }
    body {
        font-family: courier;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Give width 100% to your body and then you can change width of header to e.g. 99% so it will be smaller

Answer (score 0):

To make it the proper size you can do

```
header{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

and to keep it in the same position you can do

```
header{
position:fixed;
}
```

All together with your code it would be

```
header{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align: left;
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/adSgDvK.jpg");     
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
padding: 30px;
font-family: courier;
border: 7px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I have changed it, but the picture still moves when I resize the browser. I've just videoed my screen to show you I've changed the code, and what happens, I'll try and post it below.

Comment: @HollyYoung Well it will move when it is fixed, are you trying to just keep it still in the y or x position?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means to be honest. This is the video of what happens http://screencast.com/t/H1654SX11VR

Comment: I don't want the picture to move within the header like it does. Hope I'm making sense!

Comment: Oh, try adding back `background-position:fixed;` if removed.

Comment: Nope, picture still moves :( Can I have two different commands for background-position? As I already have background-position:center.

Comment: You can also try `background-attachment:fixed;`

Comment: Still moves, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, i just realized what you need to do is make the background-position absolute.

Comment: @HollyYoung I just figured out the issue, I was unable to see the video until now. here is what I came up with. `background-size: contain;` This will make the image as large as it can be, but no smaller.